# How to only check the Networkstatus if the needed permission is avaiable?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I work on a library that does some tricks if the user is not online. 
For this I request the network status like this:

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo info = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isConnected = !(info == null || !info.isConnected());
```

How can I only do this check if the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

is available?

I don't want to force all downstream projects of the lib to require this permission only for the tricks in the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use checkPermission utility.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#checkPermission%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

```
int res = getContext().checkCallingOrSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE);
return (res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
```